# Changing the font as in EGA

Tags: fonts

I am an algebraic geometer and I fell in love with the font they use in mathematical articles published by the IHES (for instance EGA, which I assume is the most famous of all time). How would I proceed to do that?

P.S. : I don't just want to know what to write in the code (which I assume is quite obvious), I'd also like to know *what font it is*.

EDIT : Actually I realized it only changed the font, not the math font. In EGA the math symbols are not slanted as in the standard math font... what about that? (Please don't close!)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : Sorry I couldn't find it. Definitely a duplicate!

Comment: As far as I know, it's a version of *Baskerville*.  The SMF some years ago commissioned Yannis Haralambous for a digital clone of this font (*SMF Baskerville*), but I don't think it's available.

Comment: @Bernard : I looked up the suggested link above and I picked the Baskerville font. Like the memes say, "close enough"!

Comment: I edited my question : please look it up again!

Comment: See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684570/208544) for how to change the math font to match